# Why does NitroPDF print a 500 page PDF faster than AdobePDF?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printer, dot-matrix-printer

I have a report with 500 pages, when I send to printer Adobe takes 21 seconds/page, but NitroPDF gets the job done in 15 seconds/page.

Why is NitroPDF faster?

-OS windows 10
-Printer Dot-matrix printer EPSON FX890
-Report only text (but pdf is printed as image)

Comment: Because nitrous.

Answer (score 0):

For several years, the developers of your app have [focused on performance](https://blog.gonitro.com/2015/06/fastest-document-workflows/), so presumably they [optimized their code](https://blog.gonitro.com/2014/02/nitro-pro-update-version-9-0-6-20/) for speed, when compared to Adobe.